# Plot titles in R using sapply()

Tags: r, plot, sapply

I want to make qqnorm plot out of every variable in my data frame using sapply(). This is what I've got so far:

```
myfun=function(x) {
  c(qqnorm(x),
    qqline(x)
  )
}

sapply(mydata, myfun)
```

It works, however, I'd like each plot to have the respective variable name in the title of the plot. How is this done?

Thanx a lot ;-)

Comment: Read `?qqnorm`. Pay special attention to the `main` argument.

Comment: Thanks Roland, I'm aware of the main argument, however I don't know how to set it so that it displays the name of each respective variable (in the resulting graphics produced by sapply).

Comment: Why don't you use a good old `for` loop for this? Since you don't want a return value, `*apply` loops don't offer any advantage here.

Comment: Very simple: I didn't know for loop would do the trick nor do I kno how to use it. But I'm going to learn it. Thanx for the suggestion!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case `l_ply` is more suitable because you just need to plot and therefore no output is needed. Based on @Henrik answer we have

```
require(plyr)
myfun <- function(x, data, ...) {
  c(qqnorm(data[[x]], main = names(data)[x], ...),
    qqline(data[[x]])
  )
}

l_ply(seq_len(ncol(swiss)), myfun, data = swiss)
```

**EDIT**

If you want to see your graphs, you have many options and one of them is to divide you plotting device and plot each qqplot in one part of the device.

```
par(mfrow = c(3, 2))
l_ply(seq_len(ncol(swiss)), myfun, data = swiss)
```

Comment: I like the introduction of the ellipsis (`...`), looks automatically more professional (also using `seq_len`). [I can only say one thing.](http://i.qkme.me/3qcu1t.jpg)

Comment: Sounds reasonable, it plots nothing however.

Comment: It works for me...hmmm but If you trouble use sapply or lapply then.

Comment: Still no luck. sapply and lapply return a lot of output, not graphs.

Comment: Curiously enough, rstarting R helped. Both functions work like a charm. Thank you, guys!

Comment: you probably had a non-interactive device open, and closing the R session closed it automatically. If faced with a similar problem, you can try `dev.off()` next time.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that when you do it like that the `names` are not passed over to the function, but only an unnamed list element. You need to slightly alter the function and just hand over the index and then work on the whole object (i.e., implicitly doing a for-loop and using an iterator):

```
data(swiss)

myfun=function(x, data) {
  c(qqnorm(data[[x]], main = colnames(data)[x]),
    qqline(data[[x]])
  )
}

lapply(1:ncol(swiss), myfun, data = swiss)
```

Also, I changed the function to `lapply` and use the `swiss` data set as an example.

Comment: Looks great, however it tells me lapply(1:nrow(swiss), myfun, data = swiss)
Error in .subset2(x, i, exact = exact) : subscript out of bounds when I try to use it.

Comment: Thanks for you answer, just a small typo I think you want `qqline(data[[x]])`

Comment: I figured - It gives me a lot of output, but no graphs. (Excuse my lame-ness, probably I'm just missing something obvious).

Comment: hmm, works for me. I mean, it only shows the last plot, but your question only asks for the title and this is what it adds. If you want something else, you need to perhaps change your question. (or try `dev.off()` until you get an error and then run again)

Comment: It looks like dev.off() is the solution (as also mentioned by baptiste). Thanx to all of you for decreasing my noobishness :)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a `for` loop, which is imho the most appropriate loop construct for this.

```
for (i in seq_along(swiss)) {
  qqnorm(swiss[,i], main = names(swiss)[i])
  qqline(swiss[,i])
  Sys.sleep(3) #to see something and avoid problems in RStudio
}
```

Comment: Oh yes, works perfectly. How does 3s delay help with avoiding problems? Just curious.

Comment: Well, some plots did not show in RStudio if I omitted the delay.