# output from "for" loop

Tags: r, for-loop, boxplot, outliers

based on Roland's suggestion from [Plot titles in R using sapply()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16729853/plot-titles-in-r-using-sapply), I have created the following loop to make boxplots out of every selected variable in my dataset.

```
all.box=function(x) {
  for (i in seq_along(x)) {
    boxplot(x[,i], main = names(x)[i])
  }
}
```

It does the job nicely in that it provides the graphs. Could someone point out to me how to make the loop to return some output, say the $out from the boxplot to be able to see the number of outliers calculated by it?

Thanx a lot!

Comment: I agree with @agstudy, if you want to return a result, it's more convenient to use `*apply` or `foreach` loops than setting up a `for` loop to do that efficiently. I suggested a `for` loop because you claimed to want the plots and didn't say anything about returning anything else.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `lapply` here is better to avoid side-effect of the `for`:

```
all.box=function(x) {
  res <- lapply(seq_along(x),function(i){
     boxplot(x[,i], main = names(x)[i])$out
  })
  res
}
```

PS: you can continue to use `for`, but you will need either to append a list as a result within your loop or to allocate memory for the output object before calling boxplot. So I think it is simpler to use `xxapply` family function here.

Comment: That indeed makes much more sense. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

If you want to return something from a `for` loop, it's very important to pre-allocate the return object if it's not a list. Otherwise `for` loops with many iterations will be slow. I suggest to read the [R inferno](http://www.burns-stat.com/pages/Tutor/R_inferno.pdf) and Circle 2 in particular.

```
all.box=function(x) {
  result <- list()
  for (i in seq_along(x)) {
    result[[i]] <- boxplot(x[,i], main = names(x)[i])$out
  }
  result
}
```